# Python urllib2 force IPv4

Tags: python, urllib2, ipv4

I am running a script using python that uses urllib2 to grab data from a weather api and display it on screen. I have had the problem that when I query the server, I get a "no address associated with hostname" error. I can view the output of the api with a web browser, and I can download the file with wget, but I have to force IPv4 to get it to work. Is it possible to force IPv4 in urllib2 when using urllib2.urlopen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not directly, no.

So, what can you do?

---

One possibility is to explicitly resolve the hostname to IPv4 yourself, and then use the IPv4 address instead of the name as the host. For example:

```
host = socket.gethostbyname('example.com')
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://{}/path'.format(host))
```

However, some virtual-server sites may require a `Host: example.com` header, and they will instead get a `Host: 93.184.216.119`. You can work around that by overriding the header:

```
host = socket.gethostbyname('example.com')
request = urllib2.Request('http://{}/path'.format(host),
                          headers = {'Host': 'example.com'})
page = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

---

Alternatively, you *can* provide your own handlers in place of the standard ones. But the standard handler is mostly just a wrapper around `httplib.HTTPConnection`, and the real problem is in `HTTPConnection.connect`.

So, the clean way to do this is to create your own subclass of `httplib.HTTPConnection`, which overrides `connect` like this:

```
def connect(self):
    host = socket.gethostbyname(self.host)
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, self.post),
                                         self.timeout, self.source_address)
    if self._tunnel_host:
        self._tunnel()
```

Then create your own subclass of `urllib2.HTTPHandler` that overrides `http_open` to use your subclass:

```
def http_open(self, req):
    return self.do_open(my wrapper.MyHTTPConnection, req)
```

… and similarly for `HTTPSHandler`, and then hook up all the stuff properly as shown in the `urllib2` docs.

The quick & dirty way to do the same thing is to just monkeypatch `httplib.HTTPConnection.connect` to the above function.

---

Finally, you could use a different library instead of `urllib2`. From what I remember, `requests` doesn't make this any easier (ultimately, you have to override or monkeypatch slightly different methods, but it's effectively the same). However, any `libcurl` wrapper will allow you to do the equivalent of `curl_easy_setopt(h, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE_V4)`.

Comment: Is socket a class of urllib2?

Comment: @TheDoctor: No, [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) is a module, and `socket.socket` is a class of the `socket` module.

Comment: I have gotten it working using socket, but now I get HTTP error 596: REST service not available. I have no idea how to solve this, but thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Not a proper answer but an alternative:  call `curl`?

```
import subprocess
import sys

def log_error(msg):
    sys.stderr.write(msg + '\n')

def curl(url):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ["curl", "-fsSkL4", url],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    if process.returncode == 0:
        return stdout
    else:
        log_error("Failed to fetch: %s" % url)
        log_error(stderr)
        exit(3)
```